# How to get images from child table with primer key in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have three tables in databse "cardetails", "pricedetails" and "stockimages".

I am using join in Codeigniter to get all records form above three tables. I got data from two tables but i am unable to get images data from "stockimages"

Tables details :-

```
1. Cardetails
carid Make   Model  Color Body user_id
1     Hundai Varna  White Sand  1
2     Audi   A5     White Sand  1
3     BMW    A3     White Sand  1
4     Audi   A1     White Sand  1

2. Pricedetails
priceid carid minPrice MaxPrice
1         3   15000    22000

3. stockimaes
imgid carid imagesurl
1       3    url 1
2       3    url 2
3       3    url 3
4       3    url 4
5       3    url 5
```

I want to show all cars with price and images in front page.

```
public function allCarList($userid){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('cardetails as stock' );
    $this->db->where('stock.user_id', $usrid);
    $this->db->where('deleteid != ',1);
    $this->db->join('price as p', 'stock.carid = p.carid', 'LEFT');
    $this->db->order_by('carid','desc');
    $q = $this->db->get()->result();
    return $q;
}
```

Unable to get images with all rows related with same carid.

Comment: `print_r($q)` what is it?

Comment: all data of two tables.... "cardetails" and "Pricedetails"

Comment: If you will get the stockimages data using join in these query than you will get multiple record for the car details so better is that you will create one helper function and get car images data in that by passing car id

Comment: yes. now i am getting data with helper. But i want to know how do same thing with join query.

Answer (score 0):

The issue of your code is that you are not joining the other table. You've included only join of these 2 (`cardetails`, `price`):

```
$this->db->from('cardetails as stock' );
$this->db->join('price as p', 'stock.carid = p.carid', 'LEFT');
```

What you need to do is add second join, to connect the third table, generally you can use this syntax:

```
$this->db->select('*');    
$this->db->from('table1');
$this->db->join('table2', 'table1.id = table2.id');
$this->db->join('table3', 'table1.id = table3.id');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

For your example, it would be:

```
$this->db->from('cardetails as stock' );
$this->db->join('price as p', 'stock.carid = p.carid');
$this->db->join('stockimaes as img', 'stock.carid = img.carid');
```

Comment: Please share some explanation for that code such that others can learn from it

Comment: Consider the data structure, I will set my query according to that structure may be it would be helpful for you........
$this->db->select('*');    
$this->db->from('Cardetails');
$this->db->join('Pricedetails', 'Cardetails.carid = Pricedetails.carid');
$this->db->join('stockimaes', 'Cardetails.carid = stockimaes.carid');
$query = $this->db->get();

Actually we have to implement multiple join to get data from three tables on the basis of carid.

Comment: @SyedarslanAhmed Hello, you should focus on putting your comments, all the code and stuff for the answer into the actual **answer**. Otherwise, it won't be easily readable. Comments are there for different purpose (e.g. clarifying details). I filled for you the rest of the answer, so you have the grasp how it should look like. Next time your answer might get deleted as the answer was really incomplete.